# Julia error using PyPlot - signal (11): Segmentation fault

Tags: julia

Learning to use PyPlot with Julia programming language (Version 0.4.5), I've encountered an error while trying to produce a simple plot:

```
julia> using PyPlot

julia> x = linspace(0,100,1000)
linspace(0.0,100.0,1000)

julia> y = x.^2;

julia> plot(x,y)

signal (11): Segmentation fault
unknown function (ip: 0x32736)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Someone knows what's going on here?

Comment: Do you have a high version of matplotlib (1.5.1 or something like that)? I know CentOS ships with an old version of matplotlib which will break some things. Force PyPlot to build using Conda.jl via `ENV["PYTHON"] = ""; Pkg.build("PyPlot")`. See what happens.

Comment: Hi Ohm, did you solve the problem? After an ubuntu upgrade, I get the exact same message. After rebuilding the julia packages and upgrading then I have not managed to solve the problem. Please let me know if you have made any progress.

Comment: Btw I now see that if I call "import matplotlib.pyplot"  at the python command prompt, then I get the error "RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9". Is this relevant?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your error when running on `0.4.6`.  My thoughts would be:

1. Update to latest version.
2. Update all your packages
3. Quit and restart julia
4. If none of those work, it's conceivable perhaps that the `plot` function doesn't like the mismatch of argument types.  Thus, you could apply `collect(x)` so that both `x` and `y` are of type `Array`.

Comment: Using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade julia` on Ubuntu the version stayed Version 0.4.5 ; would you recommend to build Julia from source?

Comment: @Ohm  You could, or get generic linux binaries here: http://julialang.org/downloads/   The suggestion in Chris' comment above is also quite worth trying.