# Julia PyPlot segments

Tags: matplotlib, segmentation-fault, julia

This question is related to the already asked question:
[Julia error using PyPlot - signal (11): Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476478/julia-error-using-pyplot-signal-11-segmentation-fault)

However, it is not entirely clear to me what the solution there was, or whether even the steps there apply also to my case (I tried them with no effect).

I have been using Julia 4.6 for some time without any problems.
I then decided to update my Ubuntu distribution from 14 to 16.04.
This is when PyPlot stopped working.
I have updated the Julia Packages, and I also did Pkg.build("PyPlot") to no effect. I also run Pkg.test("PyCall") and it passes all tests succesfuly. I also tried the suggestion

```
ENV["PYTHON"] = ""; Pkg.build("PyPlot")
```

The situation right now is the following.
I can import PyPLot normally:

```
using PyPlot
```

This gives me no errors.
However, as soon as I invoke any command relating to PyPlot, like:

```
figure()
```

I receive the error:

```
signal (11): Segmentation fault
unknown function (ip: 0x32736)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and Julia exits of course.

I don't know if this is relevant, but out of curioustiy I tried the following thing. After starting python in the command line, I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

which gives me the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 62, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 15, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 58, in <module>
    from matplotlib import ft2font
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

All help appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I fixed the problem in python with the import statement by simply uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib via pip. However, this changed nothing for Julia.

Comment: maybe you just need to remove the Pyplot.ji  / cached files and recompile?

Comment: You might be running into this: https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl/issues/234#issuecomment-237031105.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I managed to solve the problem with the help of a colleague.

I first re-installed matplotlib via pip.

I had to point Julia to the system installed Python:

```
ENV["PYTHON"]="/usr/bin/python"
```

I then rebuilt PyCall and PyPlot:

```
Pkg.build("PyCall")
Pkg.build("PyPlot")
```

Restarted Julia and it worked!